# Number of different elements for each columns pair

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array `A` of shape `(n, m)` and dtype `bool`:

```
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False]])
```

I would like to get the result `R` of shape `(m, m)` of dtype `int`:

```
array([[0, 3, 2],
       [3, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

where `R[i, j]` is the number of elements that are different in columns `i` and `j`. So, for example:

```
R[0, 0] = (A[:, 0] != A[:, 0]).sum()
R[2, 1] = (A[:, 2] != A[:, 1]).sum()
R[0, 2] = (A[:, 0] != A[:, 2]).sum()
...
```

Is there a way to achieve this with NumPy?

Related question: [Sum of element wise or on columns triplet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76276484/sum-of-element-wise-or-on-columns-triplet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty straightforward with some broadcasting:

```python
R = (A[:, None, :] != A[:, :, None]).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Any clue on how to solve this instead? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76276484/5296106 It's a bit more complicated version of this one

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps:

```
cols = np.arange(A.shape[1])
R = np.sum(A[:,cols.reshape(-1,1)] != A[:,cols.reshape(1,-1)], axis=0)
```