# Sum of element wise or on columns triplet

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array `A` of shape `(n, m)` and dtype `bool`:

```
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

I would like to get the result `R` of shape `(m, m, m)` of dtype `int`:

```
array([[[2, 3, 2, 4],
        [3, 3, 3, 5],
        [2, 3, 2, 4],
        [4, 5, 4, 4]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 5],
        [3, 1, 1, 4],
        [3, 1, 1, 4],
        [5, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[2, 3, 2, 4],
        [3, 1, 1, 4],
        [2, 1, 0, 3],
        [4, 4, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 5, 4, 4],
        [5, 4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 3, 3]]])
```

where `R[k, i, j]` is the sum of the element wise logical *or* on columns k, i and j. So, for example:

```
R[3, 1, 2] = (np.logical_or(np.logical_or(A[:, 3], A[:, 1]), A[:, 2])).sum()
```

One way to get this result is

```
R = np.array(
    [[[np.logical_or(np.logical_or(A[:, i], A[:, j]), A[:, k]).sum()
    for i in range(m)] for j in range(m)] for k in range(m)],
)
```

But this is clearly not using numpy APIs. Is it possible to do it using NumPy? For example, with broadcasting, see the related question below.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76276165/5296106) is a related (simpler) question.

Comment: something like `A[:,:,None] | A[:,None,:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these kinds of broadcasting problems, I usually reason about what different operations do to the shape. For example, `A[:, None, :] * A[:, :, None]` will give an array of shape `(n, m, m)`, while `A.sum(axis=0)` will remove the first axis, giving an array of shape `(m,)`.

Given that we want an output with shape `(m, m, m)`, we first broadcast axis 1 of `A` into axes 1, 2, and 3 to get an intermediate array with shape `(n, m, m, m)`, then sum over axis 0:

```
R = (A[:, :, None, None] | A[:, None, :, None] | A[:, None, None, :]).sum(axis=0)
```